# terraform CLI can't find remote cloud workspaces when using multiple tags, attempts to create them

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud, terraform-cli

I have a 'development' - 'staging' and 'production' workspace within the terraform cloud organisation.

I'm attempting to interact with them as per documentation [here.](https://www.terraform.io/cli/workspaces#interactions-with-terraform-cloud-workspaces)

Particularly this:

> If you associate the directory with multiple workspaces (using
> workspace tags), you can use the terraform workspace commands to
> select which remote workspace to use.

Locally, I also have the exact same three terraform workspaces created.

Screenshots:

- local workspaces:
  [image]
- remote workspaces and tags:

[image]

100% same organisation I was able to interact with the workspaces if I hardcode the workspace value instead of using tags.

My terraform backend cloud definitions:

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "<<myorgname>>"
    workspaces {
      tags = ["development", "staging", "production"]
    }
  }
}
```

When I run a simple `terraform init` I get greeted by:

```
No workspaces found.

  There are no workspaces with the configured tags (development, production, staging)
  in your Terraform Cloud organization. To finish initializing, Terraform needs at
  least one workspace available.

  Terraform can create a properly tagged workspace for you now. Please enter a
  name to create a new Terraform Cloud workspace.
```

I've been going through the documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/cloud-docs/run/cli) that goes into CLI-driven runs with this context but I can't figure out the right way to do this.

What I want is:

- run a `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` whilst in the locally-selected `development` workspace

and then:

- the cloud terraform to perform a run on the remote `development` workspace.

If I just go ahead and write 'development' as a name, it will then apply all 3 tags in the static definition to the remote 'development' workspace, thus defeating the whole purpose of using tags instead of a name.

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true, however there is also this part of documentation [1]:

> `tags` - (Optional) A set of Terraform Cloud workspace tags. You will be able to use this working directory with **any workspaces that have all of the specified tags**, and can use the terraform workspace commands to switch between them or create new workspaces. New workspaces will automatically have the specified tags. This option conflicts with name.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, in order for local workspaces to be usable in Terraform Cloud as well (i.e., to be able to apply the code in Terraform Cloud), there has to be a "common" or a "main" tag across all workspaces created in the Terraform Cloud.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/cli/cloud/settings#arguments

Comment: not sure I follow entirely even after reading that several times -- does it imply I could have a 'myenv' tag on all 3 of them and then, the command 'apply' would apply solely to the workspace that I'm acting as locally? either way, worth trying out

Comment: Yup, I'm reading it that way. :)

Comment: would you mind updating the answer to include the bit where you need to have a common "main" or whatever tag for all 3 workspaces and only then you can use local workspaces to target remote workspaces with the same name? that should help people in the future who are interested in the same use case, happy to mark it as the answer then. 

Thank you

Comment: Sure, I can try, but if I miss something please feel free to edit!